# Location of heated-seat relays on Chrysler Town & Country (2012)

Tags: chrysler

I have a 2012 Chrysler Town & Country with the middle row heated seats. One of them  doesn't work-- when the button is clicked, it comes on for about 2 seconds, then clicks back off. My guess is it's a bad relay, but I can't figure out where the heated seat relays are to test them. Google searching has proved unfruitful.

Can anyone point me to them?

Comment: I found the fuses but no relays.

Comment: Evidently there is a heated seat module under the seat, probably not user serviceable, heating element may be shorted............https://www.chryslerforum.com/forum/chrysler-voyager-town-country-21/2013-chrysler-t-c-drivers-heated-seat-not-working-27107/